# Python module matrix class that implements Modulo 2 arithmetic?

Tags: python, matrix, math

I'm looking for a pure Python module that implements a matrix class where the underlying matrix operations are computed in modulo 2 arithmetic as in

```
(x+y)%2
```

I need to do a lot of basic matrix manipulations ( transpose, multiplication, etc. ).

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Libraries) might help you. Look for the Matrix module on that page. Here is the [source](http://www.nightmare.com/squirl/python-ext/misc/matrix.py).

cheers